# R - how to count all words in a df row and add output to a new column? Ideally with tidyverse or tidytext

Tags: r, nlp, tidyverse

I'm trying to find the location of words in a text, and also the total wordcount of the same text.

```
# library(tidyverse)
# library(tidytext)
txt<-tibble(text=c("we're meeting here today to talk about our earnings. we will also discuss global_warming.", "hi all, global_warming and the on-going strike is at the top of our agenda, because unionizing threatens our revenue goals.", "we will discuss global_warming tomorrow, today the focus is our Q3 earnings"))
dict <- tibble(words=c("global_warming"))
x<-txt %>% unnest_tokens(output = "words",
                          input = "text",
                          drop = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(text) %>%
  mutate(word_loc = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  inner_join(dict)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  text                                                                                        words        word_loc
  <chr>                                                                                       <chr>           <int>
1 we're meeting here today to talk about our earnings. we will also discuss global_warming.   global_warm…       14
2 hi all, global_warming and the on-going strike is at the top of our agenda, because unioni… global_warm…        3
3 we will discuss global_warming tomorrow, today the focus is our Q3 earnings                 global_warm…        4
```

How can I add one column, that gives me the total word count for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_count` to get the total number of words for each string, where `\\S+` counts all sequences on non-space characters.

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  mutate(count = str_count(text, "\\S+"))
```

Or another option using base R:

```
x$count <- lengths(gregexpr("\\S+", x$text))
```

**Output**

```
  text                                           words word_loc count
  <chr>                                          <chr>    <int> <int>
1 we're meeting here today to talk about our ea… glob…       14    14
2 hi all, global_warming and the on-going strik… glob…        3    20
3 we will discuss global_warming tomorrow, toda… glob…        4    12
```

Or if you want to count contractions, words with hypens, etc. then you can use `\\w+` instead:

```
x %>%
  mutate(count = str_count(text, "\\w+"))

  text                                           words word_loc count
  <chr>                                          <chr>    <int> <int>
1 we're meeting here today to talk about our ea… glob…       14    15
2 hi all, global_warming and the on-going strik… glob…        3    21
3 we will discuss global_warming tomorrow, toda… glob…        4    12
```